# jQuery Each Incremented Counter vs. Selectors

Tags: javascript, jquery, each

I just finished an aspect of my project that required looping through the rows of an HTML table and depending on the class of the `td`, do something with the text. I approached the issue with two different methods and now I'm wondering which is considered best coding practice. Also, is there an advantage to using one method over the other?

Method 1:

```
$('#table tr').each(function(){
    var something = $(this).find('[class*=someClass]').html();
    //Do something with 'something'
});
```

Method 2:

```
var x = 0;
$('#table tr').each(function(){
    var something = $(this).find('.someClass' + x).html();
    //Do something with 'something'
    x++;
});
```

Comment: Both do 2 different things....

Comment: And by the way, `$().each(function(index){})`. use index instead of a variable. And ids are unique, so it's probably just for your example, but `$('#table').each` is useless.

Comment: @Karl-AndréGagnon Oops. Oversight. I've corrected it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This may be more opinion-based, but personally, I would do this:

```
$('#table tr').each(function(i){
    var something = $(this).find('.someClass' + i).html();
    //Do something with 'something'
});
```

The index of each element is passed as an argument.

Edit:

To expand on what Karl-AndréGagnon said, the two '.someClass' selectors will behave differently. In the first example, they will select all elements with 'someClass', regardless of any numerical suffix. The second example will only select the classes with the specified numerical suffix.

If you are doing the same thing to each '.someClass' element, regardless of the number on the class, you may not need an "each" at all, and could just start with a selector such as:

```
'#table tr [class*=someClass]'
```